# Entity Framework 6 DbFunctions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with Entity Framework 6. I have an existing third party database. This has defined various functions in the database. In a new version they have now defined the same functions in 2 schemas.

The code call looks like this

```
[System.Data.Entity.DbFunction("DbContext", "ifKategoriebaum")]
[CodeFirstStoreFunctions.DbFunctionDetails(DatabaseSchema = "dbo")]
public IQueryable<IfKategoriebaumReturnModel> IfKategoriebaum(int? kKategorie)
{
    var kKategorieParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("kKategorie", kKategorie.GetValueOrDefault());

    return ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<IfKategoriebaumReturnModel>("[DbContext].[ifKategoriebaum](@kKategorie)", kKategorieParam);
}

  [System.Data.Entity.DbFunction("DbContext", "ifKategoriebaum")]
[CodeFirstStoreFunctions.DbFunctionDetails(DatabaseSchema = "Pos")]
public IQueryable<Pos_IfKategoriebaumReturnModel> Pos_IfKategoriebaum(int? kShop)
{
    var kShopParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("kShop", kShop.GetValueOrDefault());

    return ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Pos_IfKategoriebaumReturnModel>("[DbContext].[ifKategoriebaum](@kShop)", kShopParam);
}
```

My problem is now, when EF creates the model, there is an exception because the function is defined twice.

How can I tell EF that these are 2 different?

I had already tried to add the scheme in the `DbFunctionAttribute` in the namespace (which unfortunately had no effect at all) let alone prefix the names accordingly.

The first had no effect at all, the second allows the model to be created, but that was it.

Are there other options here?

It should be mentioned in passing, the code is generated, I can adjust the generation here. I would like to keep the function in there, but if this is not possible, I would exclude it from the generation.

I would be very grateful for tips.

Comment: A DbContext is *not* a model of the database, it's a Unit-of-Work meant to serve a small set of use cases. Nothing prevents you from using multiple DbContext classes with a different set of entities. In DDD terms you'd say a DbContext should handle one bounded context.

Comment: [Review the attribute parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctionattribute.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#parameters)

Comment: This is something I've only just come to realise myself - and specifically that one context per schema is a LOT easier to setup. However, it's not always the right solution depending on your use case.